# Algorithmically track a large number of shuffled decks

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory

Lets say an application needs to efficiently store a large number of shuffled decks.  Does there exist a constant-space, constant-time, algorithm  such that:

```
 index = draw_from_shuffled(element_count, number_of_draws_made, random_seed)
```

The value returned is the index of the next card to draw from a sorted set.  In addition,  the index will not repeat,  ie:  the same card won't be drawn twice.  The need to store a large number of differently shuffled decks would be replaced with a random number which provides a kind of Initialization Vector in which to order that set of cards.  Storing a `n` number of shuffled decks, would require storing `n` number of integer values.

So does an algorithm like this exist?  One way of doing it without constant-time is to use a [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) to keep track of cards that have already been drawn.   The data requirements would be constant, but the worst case algorithmic complexity is `n!`,  which is  not desirable.

Comment: I don't see how the worst case is `n!`. I mean the worst that could happen is that the next card is the last in the deck which will result in worst case of `n`

Comment: Do you mean that the memory used by the algorithm should not depend on the number of decks?

Comment: If you really want a random number, I don't think you can find something like that in constant space and constant time. Because you need to remember what cards you have taken. Unless you want something that is not truly random, in the sense that the next draw of a card is determined by the previous draw, or two previous draws, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep an array of 52 integers where each item is the total number of the corresponding card in all decks (index 1 represents 1 of hearts and the item is initially 1000 for 1000 decks). In the draw function:

1. Pick a random value, R, between 0 and 1.
2. Set T to 0
3. For each item in array:

   3-a. Let T = T + item / totalItems

   3-b. If T >= R decrement item, decrement totalItems, return the item index

   3-c. Go to 3

This algorithm has constant space and constant runtime complexity assuming the number of decks fit in an integer. Perhaps more precisely, the space complexity is `O(logD)`.

Comment: This is exactly the algorithm I wish to avoid.   What if D was infinite?

Comment: @Rook added a new algorithm

Comment: I think algorithm II is right (and I upvoted). Can it be put in an answer on its own?

Comment: Does this algorithm have a name?  Do you have a link?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this myself and don't have any reference even if it is known